# SQL Query using Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have a table as follows:

```
PriorityText  Priority  LoRes   Partial  Unknown  N_A      HiRes
------------------------------------------------------------------
Very High     5         0.0612  0.0000   0.0612   0.0612   0.2041
High          4         0.1429  0.0000   0.1633   0.0000   0.1633
Medium        3         0.0000  0.0000   0.1020   0.0000   0.0408
Low-Medium    2         0.0000  0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
Low           1         0.0000  0.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000
```

I am tying to transpose the table into this:

```
PriorityText  Low  Low-Medium  Medium  High    Very High
--------------------------------------------------------
Priority      1    2           3       4       5
LoRes         0    0           0       0.1429  0.0612
Partial       0    0           0       0       0
Unknown       0    0           0.102   0.1633  0.0612
N_A           0    0           0       0       0.0612
HiRes         0    0           0.0408  0.1633  0.2041
```

I am using SQL 2008.  I am having trouble coming up with the SQL syntax to perform a pivot on the data.

Can someone please share a SQL snippet that will solve this for me?

I have used the following to successfully pivot one row, but I do not know how to make it do all my rows.

```
SELECT VeryHigh AS VeryHigh, 
       High AS High, 
       Medium AS Medium, 
       [Low-Medium] AS [Low-Medium], 
       Low AS Low
 FROM  (SELECT [PriorityText], [LoRes] FROM @tbTemp) p
PIVOT (SUM(LoRes) FOR [PriorityText] in ([VeryHigh], [High], [Medium], [Low-Medium], [Low])) pvt
```

My test data in my table is as follows:

```
Priority PriorityText   LoRes   Partial  Unknown   N_A    HiRes
1        VeryHigh       0.05    11       54        0      9
2        High           0.14    22       54        0      3
3        Medium         0.07    33       65        0      7
4        Low-Medium     0.01    44       87        0      4
5        Low            0       55       9         0      0
NULL     NULL           NULL    NULL     NULL      NULL   NULL
```

Thank for any help!!

Comment: For me, the Priority row in your expected result does not make sense in terms of DB design. It is not the same kind of that as the other rows, so it does not belong to the same dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how hardcoded you can make this, but what your wanting to do is Transpose the Rows with the Columns.

```
SELECT p.[Type] as 'PriorityText', Low, [Low-Medium], Medium,High,[VeryHigh]
FROM (SELECT PriorityText, [Holder],[Type]
      FROM (SELECT PriorityText,Priority,LoRes,[Partial],Unknown,N_A,HiRes
              FROM Test) as sq_source
      UNPIVOT ([Holder] FOR [Type] IN
        (Priority,LoRes,[Partial],Unknown,N_A,HiRes)) as sq_up
     ) as sq 
 PIVOT (
    MIN([Holder])
    FOR PriorityText IN
       (VeryHigh,High,Medium,[Low-Medium],Low)
       ) as p
    order by CASE p.[Type] WHEN 'Priority' THEN 1
    WHEN 'LoRes' THEN 2
    WHEN 'Partial' THEN 3
    WHEN 'Unknown' THEN 4
    WHEN 'N_A' THEN 5
    ELSE 6 END ASC;
```

This should get you what you need. One thing to note is this only works if the columns:

- Priority
- LoRes
- Partial
- Unknown
- N_A
- HiRes

are of the same data type (in my test it was decimal(5,4)). If yours are deferent then you will need to do an initial select and convert them to a common data type and use that as the sq_source.

Comment: I took your quesry and replaced 'Test' with my table name and I get the folwing error: "Msg 8167, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The type of column "LoRes" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list."  Do I need to do something else?

Comment: I mentioned at the bottom that the columns [Priority],[LoRes],[Partial],[Unknown],[N_A] and [HiRes] need to be the same data type.

e.g. if you had all of them apart from LoRes as decimal(5,4) then you need to cast LoRes as decimal(5,4).

If you send the creation script for your table I will be able to modify the sql to match what you need.